# Make banners slide from left to right

Tags: css, slider

I want to make sliding banners like
This site's homepage, is not sure if any library supports this. Thanks for the help!
https://thewebindex.org/

Comment: Can you elaborate your question? You can add the code that you tried so far. it can help us to understand what you really want to code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's called **accordion**. For example, such accordion can achieve [jQuery UI](https://jqueryui.com/accordion/).

You can also search for your favorite library with the keyword accordion :)

```js
$(function() {
  $("#accordion").accordion();
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#accordion {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}

#accordion>div {
  flex: 1;
}

#accordion>div:nth-of-type(1) {
  background: #faf;
}

#accordion>div:nth-of-type(2) {
  background: #faa;
}

#accordion>div:nth-of-type(3) {
  background: #aff;
}

#accordion>div:nth-of-type(4) {
  background: #afa;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<div id="accordion">
  <h3>Section 1</h3>
  <div></div>
  <h3>Section 2</h3>
  <div></div>
  <h3>Section 3</h3>
  <div></div>
  <h3>Section 4</h3>
  <div></div>
</div>
```